Why can I not select the tip of the bone?
I am unable to select the tip of the bone, I can only select it as a whole or select the bottom. This ends up restricting the actions I can't take as it doesn't allow me to interact with the bone properly or as i would like to.

In this image you can see how the top seems to be selected but it doesn't become orange as it usually happens, on the other hand, the bottom one does. You can also see how when in edit mode I lack the proportional editing option for some reason.



I can select both without problem. What makes you think you cannot select them individually? Did you try moving them?

Or is it just because the gizmo does not switch positions when you change the selection? Your Transform Pivot Point is set to 3D Cursor and the gizmo is always where the pivot point is. Switch it to something else like the default Median Point and the gizmo changes with the selection.


Okay I guess the quesiton should be a bit different, what weirds me out is that when I select the top tip of the bone it doesn't appear orange showing that it is selected, but it seems like I can move it regardless, however I would like to know why this happens to me. Another detail is that when I enter edit mode, I don't have the option to use proportional editing, this may have something to do with it.

Just giving this correct answer as it can be selected and asking the proper question in another post, thank you.
